# Change microphone for application programmatically

Tags: c++, windows, msdn

In a scenario where multiple microphones are present on the system. Is it possible to switch between the microphones? I am able to detect different microphones present using [EnumAudioEndPoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mmdeviceapi/nf-mmdeviceapi-immdeviceenumerator-enumaudioendpoints) but not sure if/how to switch between them. One way would be to change the system wide default microphone from within my application, but can not find an API that can do so.

Is it Possible to switch microphone from within my application from default to some other using MSDN Public API's(or otherwise)?

Comment: Do you mean microphone or speaker? I suspect you mean speaker, as you say you want to change the playback device.

Comment: No not the speakers. The application i am working on records the user audio, need to provide option to change microphone if more than one are connected.